# How can I tell if all USB-C ports on a 2020 M1 MacBook Pro are the same speed, or if one or more will be faster than others?

Tags: usb, hardware, external-disk, performance

I'm doing some heavy copying of files, and wish to do it via the fastest USB-C connection possible.

I tried holding <kbd>option</kbd> and clicking on the apple logo on the very top left, then going to System Information. From here on I'm guessing. I looked under 'Hardware' and see two areas of interest: 'Thunderbolt/USB4', and 'USB'. Does this automatically imply that one or more USB-C ports are faster than others?

#### Question

How exactly can I tell if one (or more) USB-C ports on a MacBook Pro offers faster speeds, and how can I easily know which that is?

Comment: What are you copying to / from it's probably going to be the bottleneck (not the port) - USBC (3.1) does 10Gbps, USB4 does 20 or 40Gbps depending on the hardware.

Comment: I update the title of your question. I assume you are referring to your MacBook Pro and not all MacBooks Pro models. If I am wrong, then please undo my change to your title.

Answer (score 6):

Apple Menu, "About this Mac", "System Report", "Hardware", "USB" and you get a list of all USB devices connected with their speeds. If a device is not connected directly but through a hub, that will cause a little bit of time. If multiple devices are connected to the same hub, they will have to share the bandwidth - they will slow down if they are used simultaneously.

And one trap that might be misleading you: If a hub has only slow devices connected, then it will often report that it has the slow speed itself. So a USB 3 hub with only USB 2 devices plugged in may report that it is a USB 2 hub itself; plug in a USB 3 device and it changes to a USB 3 hub.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the technical specifications which are the same for all ports on the M1 device you own (because USB-4 currently is M1 only on Apple), you could try [Blackmagic Disk Speed test](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/blackmagic-disk-speed-test/id425264550?mt=12) to test the actual speeds.

As Mr R mentioned in the comments the ports on this device usually allow for much greater transfer speeds than what your media will support. HDDs usually write/read at about 200 MB/s and depending on the SSD model you can reach GB speeds. Modern M.2 NVMe SSDs can actually exceed the 5GB/s speeds port limit, yet at that point you don't only need a very capable SSD and enclosure, but also your M1 Mac needs to handle these speeds. E.g. the internal M1 SSD maxes out at roughly 3GB/s.

Comment: I believe there are Thunderbolt 3 enclosures that can hold SDD drives that are faster than the 40 GB/s Thunderbolt 3 interface. So your statement *"the ports allow for much greater transfer speeds than what your media will support"* would not necessarily be true.

Comment: AFAIK there is no SSD that can exceed the 5GB/s limit. So you would need something like a RAID system to gain more speed. But at that point I am sure that its not the port limiting performance, because even if you read directly from the M1 SSD you won't be faster than 3GB/s. So even *if* you had something spectacular fast on the storage side, copying from your MacBook to that system will be limited not by the port IMO.

Comment: I can not correct my posted comment, but I meant 40 Gb/s.

Comment: @X_841 There are plenty of NVMe SSDs out there that can beat 5GB/s effective throughput (I have four between the three systems sitting next to me right now), and you can find M.2 Thunderbolt 3 enclosures for less than 100 USD. Whether you can actually hit that performance level is another question, because you have to be handling things in a massively parallel manner to do so (speaking from experience, because I’ve managed to do it on a couple of occasions on two out of the three aforementioned systems).

Comment: You are correct and my previous comment was wrong in that regard. Yet, if the OP is asking how to test these speeds, I doubt he owns such hardware. Thank you anyway, I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have a 2020 model year MacBook Pro with the M1 chip. Your Mac has two USB C ports. Both support USB4, which [according to Apple](https://www.apple.com/lae/macbook-pro-13/specs/) can achieve speeds up to 40 Gb/s. AFAIK there are no USB4 drives yet available for purchase. Thunderbolt 3 drives will work with your Mac and also operate as speeds up to 40 Gb/s, but Thunderbolt 3 drives are not compatible with USB 3.2 or previous versions of USB. There exists USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 drives, which operate at speeds up to 20 Gb/s. However, Apple specifications for your Mac do not mention USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 support. Apple's specifications for your Mac does show support for USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gb/s). This is also known as USB 3.2 Gen 2x1. An example of a USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 drive would be the [Samsung T7 Portable SSD](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/portable/t7/). This drive is backward compatible all the way to USB 1.1 and comes with USB type C and A cables.

User [X_841](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/355336/x-841) posted in a comment to another answer that the *"M1 SSD ... won't be faster than 3GB/s."* If this is true, then you might consider a Thunderbolt 3 drive such as the [Samsung X5](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/portable/x5/), which has a read/write speeds of 2.8/2.3 GB/s and supports TRIM. Thunderbolt 3 is compatible with the newest Macs and many newer PC's. Be aware that you can not connect a Samsung X5 to an older Mac with Thunderbolt 1 or 2 though Apple's [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter). The reason is that the drive is not self powered and the adapter can not provide power.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120842/discussion-between-david-anderson-and-jorg-w-mittag).

Answer (score 0):

So both ports provide the same speed.

I’m using a WD P50 external drive USB c 3.2 Gen 2x2 which is theoretically at 2000 Mbps.

I’m seeing those speeds in the initial burst of Black Magic Disk Test.

In real world, I’m getting 1000 Mbps with this drive sustained write of 100Gb.

There are 3 possible speed bottlenecks in this scenario:

1. USB port
2. NVMe controller in enclosure
3. Drive speed
   (Cable can also affect this)

There is deliberate vaguely from Apple about the USB 4 implementations on this board because the USB 4 standard does not make it mandatory to support USB-C 3.2 Gen 2x2.

The fact I’m seeing a burst in Black Magic suggests the drive is trying to push 20 Gbps thru but that the port is only letting 10 thru.

Gen 2x2 is only allowing 10 Gbps, TB3 external NVMe enclosure is getting 2.3 Gbps sustained 100GB writes with Sabrent gold 1TB NVMe.

Comment: I’ve done preliminary testing of the m1 with all kinds of drives and hubs. Currently in testing a tb3 enclosure to see what kind of speeds we can get. You hub and cables need to be up to spec I’ve tested 3.1/3.2 gen 2 x 1 speeds up to 700MBps on t7 Samsung I’m getting TB3 write speeds on tb3 up to 1200MBps then slowing considerably to 300MBps, probably caused by cheap nvme in the enclosure. I’m ordering a high end nvme gen 4 with a large cache which can be the reason the transfer slows down with large files. I’ll try to post back my results